# Can I run/host my own private block explorer?

Tags: blockchain, block-explorer, github

I host my own node because I want my privacy level to be as high as possible.  But if I want to view my transactions on the blockchain, right now I have to use a block explorer that someone else is hosting.  That seems not ideal for privacy.

Is there an open source block explorer that can be downloaded or cloned and built from, say, GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is, and people do host it themselves, and for others:

You can download it here:

- https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer

An example running is here: http://explore.moneroworld.com/